# Specifying a template for custom post type pages

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, custom-post-type-archives

My main projects page is bringing in some data that I have entered in for custom post types. There are basically a few categories like "photo", "video", etc.  When you click on one of these it will go to a subpage like /projects/photo/1.  How to I go about specifying a template to use for those subpages?

I am using the Ultimate Post-Type Plugin, but that shouldn't really matter since it should work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) that WordPress follows.
Since the sub page is a single custom post type. You could put the code you require to output for the sub pages in single-[post-type].php